# can't display data form json object with Object.values and .map in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change my API from containing array to containing object. I tried to map my object so I can use it on bootstrap card. it's show error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). How can I fix this ? also the console.log show 0 array meanwhile it suppose to be 1

here's my object example:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Monitor LG 24 INch",
            "description": "Ini adalah sebuah monitor",
            "weight": 1,
            "price": 13,
            "stock": 2,
            "datetime_added": "2022-02-21T12:27:06.878894Z",
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/dsada.jpg",
            "brand": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "LG",
                "image": null
            },
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Electronic",
                "image": null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

my app code:

```
const Categorized = () => {
 const [getData, setGetData] =useState([]);

 useEffect(()=>{ 
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/products/?format=json`).then(res => {
        const products = Object.values(res.data);
        setGetData(products);
      })
 }, []);

 console.log(getData)

  return (
    <Row>
      {getData && getData.results.map(product =>{
        const {id, category,image} = product;
        return(
        <Col lg={3} className="d-flex">
          <Card key={id} className="productlist flex-fill">
            <Card.Img variant="top" src={image} width="50%"/>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>{category}</Card.Title>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        )
      })}
    </Row>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you put the console.log inside the useEffect hook and see if that fixes your console.log problem?

Also why are you converting your results to an object? Map only works on an array. So you can just map through the array and it will print out a card for each element in that array.

Comment: Can you console.log(products) and see what you get? Object.values will return an array of all the values. It won't return the keys. So although it will be janky, getData[3].map might work.

Comment: I think they're better off leaving it as an array and mapping through that, surely they want a card per product yeah?

Comment: my backend developer make the api this way. I have to find way to extract the data

Comment: But are you looking to loop through all the products returned and output a card per product?

Comment: I want to access the result at json and map all of them and use the data title, image, brand,etc.  in each product

Comment: See my answer below. I believe this is what you want to do, loop through all the products and output a card per product.

Comment: it shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242274/discussion-between-john-mcaulay-and-kim-san).

Answer (score 0):

It's better to set the raw data instead of `Object.values`

```
const Categorized = () => {
 const [getData, setGetData] =useState([]);

 useEffect(()=>{ 
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/products/?format=json`).then(res => {
        setGetData(res.data); // set data directly
      })
 }, []);

 console.log(getData)

  return (
    <Row>
      {getData && getData.results.map(product =>{
        const {id, category,image} = product;
        return(
        <Col lg={3} className="d-flex">
          <Card key={id} className="productlist flex-fill">
            <Card.Img variant="top" src={image} width="50%"/>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>{category}</Card.Title>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        )
      })}
    </Row>
  )
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no time today

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const Categorized = () => {
 const [getData, setGetData] = useState([]);

 useEffect(()=>{ 
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/products/?format=json`).then(res => {
        setGetData(products);
        console.log(getData)
      })
 }, []);



  return (
    <Row>
      {getData && getData.results.map(product =>{
        
        return(
        <Col lg={3} className="d-flex">
          <Card key={product.id} className="productlist flex-fill">
            <Card.Img variant="top" src={product.image} width="50%"/>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>{product.category}</Card.Title>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        )
      })}
    </Row>
  )
}
```